# Homestead をダウンロードするとOpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54と出る

Tags: macos, laravel, vagrant, openssl

virtual box とvagrantをインストールした後、vagrant box add laravel/homestead
と打ったがhomestead のインストールがうまくいきません。
5回くらい試しましたが、同じエラーが出ます。
通信速度が遅い環境にいるのでそれが原因かもですが、タイムアウトの際は errno60 が出る
という情報もあり謎です。
/Users/apple/.vagrant.d/tmp 配下のファイルは毎回消してます。

以下バージョン情報です。
macOS:10.13.6
vagrant:2.2.2
openSSL:LibreSSL 2.2.7

他に思い当るものがなく手詰りしてしまってます
参考情報でもなんでもかまいませんので、書込みいただけると助かります。
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

解決しました！
おそらく原因は通信速度が遅いことによるタイムアウトか、
Macがスリープになってしまったことによる通信断でした。